# mysql connect perfectly first time, second time return a nullpointer

Tags: java, mysql

This is my connection Class/Method:

```
static Connection connection = null;
        Statement stm = null;

public static Connection getConexao() {
            try {  
                // Carregando o JDBC Driver padrão  
                String driverName = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";                          
                Class.forName(driverName);  
                // Configurando a nossa conexão com um banco de dados//  
                String serverName = "192.168.0.222";    //caminho do servidor do BD  
                String mydatabase ="bd";        //nome do seu banco de dados  
                String url = "jdbc:mysql://" + serverName + "/" + mydatabase;  
                String username = "user";        //nome de um usuário de seu BD        
                String password = "pass";      //sua senha de acesso  
                connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password);  
                return connection;  
            }  catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {  //Driver não encontrado  
                System.out.println("O driver expecificado nao foi encontrado.");  
                return null;  
            } catch (SQLException e) {  
                //Não conseguindo se conectar ao banco  
                System.out.println("Nao foi possivel conectar ao Banco de Dados.");  
                return null;  
            }  

    }
```

method that are called when  the TextField lost focus :

```
private void puxaemailsiscart(String servico) throws SQLException {
                Connection conn = ConectaBD.getConexao();
                Statement stm = null;
                ResultSet results = null;  
                 stm = conn.createStatement ();


                                    try {
                      System.out.println();
                      results = stm.executeQuery ("SELECT * FROM  " + servico + " WHERE protocolo =" + tfProtocolo.getText());
                      if(results.next()) {

                      tfEmailParte.setText(results.getString("Email").toString());


                      } else { 
                          System.out.println("Protocolo nao encontrado");


                      }
                      results.close();
                      stm.close();
                      conn.close();
....
```

The problem is, the first time the TextField lost the focus, it works PERFECTLY and return the Database result, but when i put the focus in the textfield and it lost focus again, the connection return null, why? since the steps are the same as the first time??

STACKTRACE

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at telaprincipal$3.puxaemailsiscart(telaprincipal.java:499)
    at telaprincipal$3.focusLost(telaprincipal.java:482)
```

Line 499: = `Connection conn = ConectaBD.getConexao();` says that here is the NullPoint, but Why?

Comment: Is `ConectaBD` a class instance (an object) or the class itself?

Comment: Your `getConexao` method returns null if an exception is thrown (having effectively swallowed the exception without logging its details, I note) but you're using the return value regardless.

Comment: do you get System.out.println("O driver expecificado nao foi encontrado."); or System.out.println("Nao foi possivel conectar ao Banco de Dados."); on your console?

Comment: 1. Try to close the connection after using it

Comment: ConectaBD is the instance... ClassThatConnect conectaDB = new ClassthatConnect();

Comment: @JohnnyAW it return "Não foi possivel connectar", that is the same as "Impossible to connect to the database" in english!!

Comment: ran i have a method that close after, but dont worked too, it close, but the problem is not the opened connection, is that it even cant connect :|

Comment: try to close connection, or try to use the same connection for next request, save the connection instance and return it if connection!= null

Comment: @JohnnyAW, but how can i use the same connection? since i have to close it?!?

Comment: In the SQLException, can you please add `e.printStackTrace()` and tell us what that says?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis sorry man, i forget this, here the new stacktrace:  invalid database address: 

    jdbc:mysql://192.168.0.222/bd
     at org.sqlite.JDBC.createConnection(JDBC.java:110)
     at org.sqlite.JDBC.connect(JDBC.java:87)
     at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
     at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)

Comment: but why it return invalid database in the second try? since the first the database is VALID -_-!!

Answer (score 0):

I believe you have an sqlite driver on our classpath that somehow got loaded after the first cycle and is trying to parse your jdbc url. If you don't use sqlite, please make remove it from your runtime classpath.

Also, if you want to open a new connection every time you call getConexao(), don't store the connection as a static. Also the second statement seems to be unnecessary (and could lead to unexpected behavior), so I suggest removing:

```
Statement stm = null;
```